# How do I store a simple int variable on a server from radio buttons in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net

```
<input type="radio" name="Column" value="A" checked> A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Column" value="B" checked> B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Column" value="C" checked> C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Column" value="D" checked> D<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Column" value="E" checked> E<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Column" value="F" checked> F<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Column" value="G" checked> G<br>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-padding-large w3-large w3-margin-top">Submit</button>
```

I have these radio buttons and I want to count how many people selected each option like a survey. I need to increment the variable by one each time it is selected however I cannot seem to find any way to accomplish this. If I submit it using "post" with PHP then does it store the variable that another user could then echo? I just need some help or guidance, even a direction of where to start. In short, I need every one that visits my page to submit an answer to the question, and then I need to store that information to view later and display the results to the users.

Comment: It's up to you to manage the back end storage and to increment the counts wherever you store it.

Comment: Yes I know, however I don't know how to do that

Comment: Do you have any PHP already?

Comment: None so far other than a simple post from w3 Schools

Comment: Is that working?

Comment: I don't have any php file so I don't know where the variable is going. Where does it get stored?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think Yoandro is saying each user that sends data will have their own PHP process. Therefore when the data is received by the PHP process, you can store it in any variable you want, but it won't be accessible by anyone else, so you'll need to save it in a file or a database so that it can be accessed from every PHP process.

Comment: Eduard you can store it in several possible ways. You could run a service and POST to that, but that would be lost on server restart if you do not store it in a file or a database. We know you do not have a file or database for this purpose. You need to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to POST the user's choice to the server, without that the server will not have the necessary information to display it to other users.

However, you already feel that there is another part, we need to echo the value, but we need to echo the sum value, therefore you will need to use a storage where you will have the necessary value which can be reached anytime, either for displaying purpose, or for incrementation. You can use a file, or a db on your server-side. In general, a db is recommended for various reasons.

Scenario of loading:

- user clicks on a link which leads to a page
- the page has to display this value
- the GET request is sent to the server
- the server will ask for the sum from the db/file
- the server responds with the page, which contains the value
- the value is displayed on the page

Scenario of updating

- user sends a POST request to the server
- the server increments the database value
- the server sends back the response to the POST

Comment: Is there a reason for the down-vote?

Comment: I upvoted, idk why it would get downvoted

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is executed in each user's own browser, in order to track and share the info among users, you need to submit the data to the server and make it persist in some type of storage, whether it be files or a database, each PHP process will as well be tied to a single user call, so... yes you have to store the results in a server (with PHP or any other) and later render them back to any other user.

I hope this helps

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking.

Comment: My answer is related to the original question, so please do not disqualify it without reason. I explained what needs to happen.

Comment: What do you mean "original question"?

Comment: This question.  If I submit it using "post" with PHP then does it store the variable that another user could then echo?

Comment: Ok I mis-read your answer, it does actually answer the question, my apologies. I can't remove my downvote unless you edit your post, however.

Comment: Edited, thanks reviewing my answer again

Comment: This is a good answer as well